# Direct product totalization in the definition of hypercohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ be a cochain complex of sheaves on $X$. The *hypercohomology* $\mathbb{H}^i(X,\,\mathcal{F}^\bullet)$ is defined as
$$\mathbb{H}^i(X,\,\mathcal{F}^\bullet)=\mathrm{H}^i[\mathrm{Tot}^{\prod}\Gamma(I^{\bullet\bullet})]\,,$$
where $I^{\bullet\bullet}$ is a(ny) *Cartan-Eilenberg resolution* of $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ and $\mathrm{Tot}^{\prod}$ means the *direct product* totalization.

My question is that are there any particular reasons why we use the direct product totalization instead of the direct sum totalization? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no difference for cohomology computation here:  At level $i$, one only needs $i$ or $i+1$ vector spaces. So the direct product and direct sum are the same.

Comment: @AGlearner If the cochain complex is not bounded below, then direct product totalization and direct sum totalization are different.

Comment: That's true, I was thinking about injective resolution of a single sheaf. Actually, I don't even know an example in which the cochain complex is not bounded below.

Comment: @AGlearner Suppose you have a chain complex of sheaves. After inverting the index, you could get a cochain complex that is not bounded below.

Comment: I mean, I don't know an example that comes "in nature".